# Why did the VIX trade for so much around Q4 2011?

Tags: historical-data, market-indexes, volatility, history

It looks like the TVIX in 2011 was trading at some unimaginable prices.  $2B USD?  Marketwatch has these same numbers.

Were these numbers real?  How?  This seems like an amazing bit of trivia from the time.

[image: TVIX in 2011]

Comment: One would expect that a leveraged VIX ETF would be elevated post 9/11 but $2B defies logic.  Sometimes Yahoo and similar mismanage stock splits (TVIX) has had multiple reverse splits) and sometimes they just provide bad data.  My guess is that it's the latter reason.

Comment: Some of these really have reverse split that many times.  @OP: It's showing you the 2011 value of one of today's shares.  Because of all the reverse splits, today's share was somewhere upwards of a million shares in 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed 25 million shares in 2011 in order to have one share today, due the SEVEN reverse split actions on that ticker.  Those 25 million shares would have cost you roughly 2 billion USD.

[image]

Source: https://www.splithistory.com/?symbol=tvix